# Hide value inside viewcontroller on UIWebView from another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I have viewcontroller A, B, C. viewcontroller A having UIWebView for displaying HTML pages and it highlight string values on UIWebView. For requirement, When i coming from viewcontroller B, viewcontroller A need to display the highlighting text on UIWebView. When i coming from viewcontroller C, viewcontroller A no need to display the highlighting text. But when i coming from viewcontroller B & C, the viewcontroller A displaying the highlight text. How to hide the highlight text on UIWebView while coming from viewcontroller C. Is it possible? How to know i'm coming from viewcontroller B or C? If it's find then maybe have a solution

viewcontroller A :

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

      wbCont = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45, 320, 568)];


      [wbCont loadHTMLString:webString baseURL:nil];

        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        // getting an NSString
        NSString  *savedValue = [prefs stringForKey:@"got"];


       if (self.displayHighlightedText) {


                if(savedValue){


[self highlightAllOccurencesOfString1:savedValue];

}


}
```

[self.view addSubview:wbcont];

viewcontroller B :

```
viewcontroller B *det = [[viewcontroller B alloc] init];

    NSString *decodeString = [self htmlEntityDecode:content];


    [content release];

    det.webString = decodeString;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:det animated:YES];
```

viewcontroller C :

```
viewcontroller c *det = [[viewcontroller C alloc] init];

    NSString *decodeString = [self htmlEntityDecode:content];


    [content release];

    det.webString = decodeString;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:det animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `BOOL` property for view controller `A` which tells it if to display highlighted text or not. Add the following to your view controller `A` interface .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL displayHighlightedText;
```

When you push/modal your `A` view controller set the property to the required value (i.e. from view controller `C` set to false and from `B` set to `true`)

Use this property in your `viewDidLoad` method of view controller `A` :

```
if (self.displayHighlightedText) {
   [self highlightAllOccurencesOfString1:savedValue];
}
```

In your edited code for viewcontroller `C` add before pushing `det` view controller:

```
det.displayHighlightedText = NO;
```

In your edited code for viewcontroller `B` add before pushing `det` view controller:

```
det.displayHighlightedText = YES;
```

Comment: I didn't understand..sorry I have tabbar for all viewcontroller

Comment: look at my edited answer... define a boolean property in VC A and use this boolean to decide if to highlight text or not. You set this property in each one of your other view controllers before pushing the A controller

Answer (score 1):

Just pass BOOL flags from one viewController to next viewController.It will solve your problem.

In AViewController while switching from AViewController to BViewController pass BOOL flag like this -

```
BViewController *aViewController = [[BViewController alloc]init];
bViewController.passFlag = TRUE;
[self.navigationController bViewController animated:YES];
```

But declare this in BViewController.h -

```
@property(nonatomic)BOOL passFlag;
```

and in BViewController.m -

```
@synthesize passFlag;
```

Now, in BViewController check -

```
if(passFlag){
  // highlight text
}else{
  // remove highlighting text
}
```

In this way you can pass BOOL flags from BViewController to CViewController.

Hope this will helps you.Thank you.

Comment: How to pass BOOL flags?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution can be using [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). 
Idea is posting notifications when you travel from view controller C or B to A with the class name of source view controller encapsulated in it, so the receiver of the notification (in this case it will we view controller A) can read the class and determine what to do when the notification is received. Here is some code to do the job

```
    //In your B or C view controller exactly before you travel from them to A.
    //If you use UINavigationController and your root controller is A, then you'll have something similar to this
    //In case you are in view controller "B"
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ViewControllerChanged" object:@"B"];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

//In your A view controller you'll have something similar to this
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(viewControllerChanged:) name:@"ViewControllerChanged" object:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

-(void)viewControllerChanged:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSString * controllerName = notification.object;
    if([controllerName isEqualToString:@"B"])
    {
        //Put code to show the highlighted text here
    }
    else if([controllerName isEqualToString:@"C"])
    {
        //Put code to hide the highlighted text here
    }
}
```